# ssh(cygwin) service stop after successfully connecting one time

Tags: cygwin, sshd

i have install cygwin and configure the ssh 
service completely

but after accessing the computer from 
another pc and when i 
logout from that the service stop

automatically and next time
 it refuse the connection.

it's on windows 7 and the firewall is turned off.
Help please
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into this same issue. Try regenerating the ssh config file. Also be aware that your user name is case sensitive because of the config file and cygwin doing its magic.